# Regex for escaping some single quotes

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I was creating some regex for matching strings like :
'pulkit'
'989'
basically anything in between the two single quotes.
so I created a regex something like `['][^']*[']`.

But this is not working for cases like:
'burger king's'. The expected output is `burger king's` but from my logic
it is `burger king` only.
As an another example `'pulkit'sharma'` the expected output should be `pulkit'sharma`

So can anyone help me in this ? How to escape single quotes in this case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not the 's' the problem is with single quote before s.

Comment: So, you need the part of string between the quotes, I added the code to get those values in case there are multiple ones in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You may match single quote that is not preceded with a word char and is followed with a word char, and match any text up to the `'` that is preceded with a word char and not followed with a word char:

```cs
(?s)\B'\b(.*?)\b'\B
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%5cB%27%5cb%28.*%3f%29%5cb%27%5cB&i=+%27burger+king%27s%27+++%27burger+king%27++%27pulkit%27sharma%27.+don%27t).

Note you do not have to wrap single quotation marks with square brackets, they are not special regex metacharacters.

C# code:

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?s)\B'\b(.*?)\b'\B")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: No the s' is not the problem. For example if the input is 'pulkit'sharma'. The output should be pulkit'sharma. Means that i want everything between two single quotes.

Comment: @PulkitSharma I understand you have not come up with the pattern requirements yet, so I am now guessing. See my updated solution and explanation what this means at the top. If it isn't what you need, please explain in details **what** you need.

Comment: Not only word char I want everything between two single '. for example 'wings (5)' output should be wings (5).

Comment: @PulkitSharma Do you just want `'(.*)'`? See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%28.*%29%27&i=+%27burger+king%27s%27%0d%0a+++%27burger+king%27%0d%0a++%27pulkit%27sharma%27.%0d%0a+don%27t%0d%0a%27wings+%285%29%27). You need to be very specific with regex requirements when it comes to matching strings between two identical chars, especially when you need to also match these chars in between these chars. Do you realize the complexity of what you are trying to do? Are you sure it can be done with regular language? Please help  by explaining the context of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try a positive lookahead to match a space or end of line for matching the closing single quote

```regex
'.+?'(?=\s|$)
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27.%2B%3F%27%28%3F%3D%5Cs%7C%24%29&i=%27pulkit%27sharma%27%20%27burger%20king%27s%27%20%27pulkit%27%20%27989%27%0D%0A%20)